# Need to upgrade from .Net 2 to a newer version?

Tags: c#, .net

We have a small application that is based on the .NET 2 Framework (C#) and is compatible with WindowsXP to Windows 8 but only 32bit (because our build machine was always 32bit too). 
We are now looking to make some changes and also create a 64 bit version now.

My question is now, **should we also upgrade to a newer version of the .NET Framework** to be ready for the future or can we just stay with our existing .NET Framework 2.

*It should still be compatible to Windows XP and all newer Windows (32 and 64 bit).*

Comment: In abstract yes, why not but, if it works you don't need to change anything.

Comment: How small?  If it's really small then even if something breaks when you upgrade to a later version of .NET, it should be too timely to fix.  So, I would make the jump.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx

Comment: We had the same in our company. We upgraded to version 4.0 as it is still compatible with windows xp and has some nice new features.

Comment: Great, I forgot to mention, how about embedded Windows XP?

Comment: Why close this question? It is both constructive and relevant. There are several concrete pros/cons with upgrading.

Comment: @AndersForsgren because there are several concrete pros/cons with upgrading. Whilst the question is relavent there is not necessarily a right answer. It depends on a number of factors and a level of judgement is required to make a subjective assessment. Either way, its moot, its going to work either way in 99.9% of cases.

Comment: Most questions on SO don't have a definitive right answer. The important bit here is providing the necessary facts to make the decision. A good answer should simply provide the necessary details for making the decision.

Answer (score 4):

You can always  upgrade it to version 4 of framework and it will still be compatible with the previous versions of windows.

Apart from that, you should always build the .Net application with "Any CPU". It will generate the intermediate code and later the JIT compiler will compile it to either 32bit or 64bit architecture depending on what machine it is being executed.

You should bother about CPU architecture only if you are referencing any unmanaged dll in your .Net application.

yes, It will still remain compatible to windows XP and all newer version of windows too. With upgrade to framework 4, you must have windows XP sp 3 as framework will not install otherwise.

As far as I know, framework 4.5 can only be installed on windows 7 or higher so upgrading to framework 4.5 might not be the option for you.

Comment: Great, I forgot to mention, how about embedded Windows XP?

Comment: Will it really "always" be compatible?  What about breaking changes http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes

Comment: If it has to break, it will break in the first instance. If you could successfully upgrade - build and run the app with new framework, it will surely continue to work. By tradition framework patches and update never break the binary compatibility but in extreme cases, there can be exception.

Comment: If it used to work with embedded windows xp before, it will continue to work.

Comment: @user1477388 - What you are pointing at is Asp.Net changes and not applicable to windows forms application.

Comment: @MurtuzaKabul Good point, but I thought the same would apply in the windows forms world as it does it web forms in terms of there being things that would break depending on the version.

Comment: @user1477388 - Well, do not deny it completely. However, whenever it will happen, it will be an exception, not a routine. You can largely rely on Microsoft for binary compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to .NET 3.5 or 4.0 shouldn't pose a problem, the drawback being that fewer people will have the framework installed, and the benefit being that you get a better CLR and can use some new language features.

If you aren't going to change the application source, you won't take advantage of any new language features, and you are only going to add a new dependency (the newer framework) for the end user. I can't see any point in going from 2.0 to 4.0 in that case.

If you are going to continue developing the application at all, then I highly recommend moving to 3.5 or 4.0 to get the new features in those frameworks, most importantly LINQ.

Do note that the 4.5 Framework isn't compatible with Windows XP so ***you can't upgrade to 4.5 if you want to keep backwards compatibility with XP***. As long as you need to target XP you are stuck with 4.0 or less.

As for output platforms, I recommend compiling like this:

- Assemblies with native dependencies: Explicitly compile x86 and x64.
- Entry point assemblies (.exe's basically): Explicitly compile for x86 and x64.
- All other assemblies: Compile as AnyCPU.

Using explicit platform for executables is a good principle because it is least surprising for the user, and allows users on 64bit systems to run the 32bit application if they want. See this blog post for a longer answer http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/09/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx

Comment: Perfect answer! Well Windows XP is still very important - so the 4.5 version is not an option. I just read that embedded XP supports up to 3.5, so I guess we'll stay with .NET 2 until we really see problem with future windows versions, but so far .NET 2 work also on new Windows 8 machines. Thanks